# Why the air is more compressed near to the ground

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

I'm studying the adiabatic effect of the air on the atmosphere but i can't understand why the compression near to the ground is higher, is something relate to the higher pressure caused by the earth irradiation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a glass of water, every molecule of water is under the influence of the gravitational potential field. Each molecule pushes down on the molecules below. The molecules of water near the bottom of the glass experience the downward force from all molecules above them (each molecule transfers the force downward). If you made a hole near the bottom of the glass, water flows out due to this pressure (Force / unit area).

Similarly, gas molecules in the atmosphere exert a downward force on the molecules below them. The molecules near the surface of the earth must bear the maximum downward force. The gas molecules also tend to flow out (like in the example of making a hole near the bottom of the glass), but here it's as if the walls of the  glass have been extended so far around the Earth that they merge on the opposite side of the Earth, making a "wall-less" container. Also, it's interesting to mention that acceleration due to gravity decreases as you go higher up. So, the downward force exerted by molecules in the upper atmosphere is less as well.